# Remove server.policy from sun application server

Tags: java

I encounter `java.lang.StackOverflowError` error after deployment of the java web application (`.war`). If I remove the `server.policy` file. I will not encounter this error however it means that there will be no security. I realize that the error will occur if I include the following in `server.policy` which by default is included permission `java.lang.RuntimePermission` - `modifyThreadGroup`;

If inside the `server.policy` file I just remove this permission `java.lang.RuntimePermission`  - `modifyThreadGroup`;

I will get access denied as by default the security manager will check for this permission.

Anyone have any idea what is wrong and how do I resolve this?

`java.lang.StackOverflowError`

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way to get a `StackOverflowError` due to having security enabled is by not giving code that is involved in security checks privileges. So I guess it's something to do with your configuration, perhaps where a codeBase has changed or exactly the same code appears in the search order before the code given privileges.